# Package i18n does not translate

Tags: go

I try to write my first package in golang. This package is only a wrapper struct from [goi18b](https://github.com/nicksnyder/go-i18n). Look at the following code.

i18n.go

```
package i18n

import (
    "fmt"
    goi18n "github.com/nicksnyder/go-i18n/i18n"
)

var translateFunc goi18n.TranslateFunc

type I18n struct {
}

func NewI18n(filename string, language string) *I18n {
    goi18n.MustLoadTranslationFile(filename)
    translateFunc, _ = goi18n.Tfunc(language)
    return new(I18n)
}

func (i18n *I18n) ReadText(translationID string, args ...interface{}) string {
    fmt.Println(translateFunc("person_unread_email_count", 1, map[string]interface{}{
        "Person": "Bob",
    }))
    return translateFunc(translationID, args)
}
```

and the test file i18n_test.go

```
package i18n

import "testing"
import "fmt"

var i18n *I18n = NewI18n("en-us.all.json", "en-US")

func TestComplexText(t *testing.T) {
    var str string
    str = i18n.ReadText("person_unread_email_count", 1, map[string]interface{}{
        "Person": "Bob",
    })
    fmt.Println(str)
}
```

as output I've got

```
Bob has 1 unread email.
person_unread_email_count
PASS
```

As you can see, inside i18n.go, text is go to translate.

```
Bob has 1 unread email.
```

But in i18n_test.go, I expect the same result, but I've got

```
person_unread_email_count
```

I can't configure out, what I do here wrong!

**Update:**

When I change the readtext function to

```
func (i18n *I18n) ReadText(translationID string, args ...interface{}) string {
    fmt.Println(translateFunc(translationID, 1, map[string]interface{}{
        "Person": "Bob",
    }))
    fmt.Println(translateFunc(translationID, args))
    return translateFunc(translationID, args)
}
```

as output I've got

```
Bob has 1 unread email.
person_unread_email_count
```

I think the error is on parameter args ...interface{}. When I pass the parameter args

```
fmt.Println(translateFunc(translationID, args))
```

the text is not go to translate. But like this, it is go to translate

```
fmt.Println(translateFunc(translationID, 1, map[string]interface{}{
    "Person": "Bob",
}))
```

why?

I forgot to post json file

```
[
  {
    "id": "d_days",
    "translation": {
      "one": "{{.Count}} day",
      "other": "{{.Count}} days"
    }
  },
  {
    "id": "my_height_in_meters",
    "translation": {
      "one": "I am {{.Count}} meter tall.",
      "other": "I am {{.Count}} meters tall."
    }
  },
  {
    "id": "person_greeting",
    "translation": "Hello {{.Person}}"
  },
  {
    "id": "person_unread_email_count",
    "translation": {
      "one": "{{.Person}} has {{.Count}} unread email.",
      "other": "{{.Person}} has {{.Count}} unread emails."
    }
  },
  {
    "id": "person_unread_email_count_timeframe",
    "translation": {
      "one": "{{.Person}} has {{.Count}} unread email in the past {{.Timeframe}}.",
      "other": "{{.Person}} has {{.Count}} unread emails in the past {{.Timeframe}}."
    }
  },
  {
    "id": "program_greeting",
    "translation": "Hello world"
  },
  {
    "id": "your_unread_email_count",
    "translation": {
      "one": "You have {{.Count}} unread email.",
      "other": "You have {{.Count}} unread emails."
    }
  }
]
```

Answer (score 0):

By default the [`go test`](http://golang.org/cmd/go/#hdr-Test_packages) tool will not print any output on success. You can override this by using the [`log`](http://golang.org/pkg/testing/#T.Log) functions from package [`testing`](http://golang.org/pkg/testing/) and setting the `-v` flag when running the tests.

See http://golang.org/cmd/go/#hdr-Description_of_testing_flags for more details.

Comment: I think the problem on args `...interface{}`. When modify readText function like this `func (i18n *I18n) ReadText(translationID string, args ...interface{}) string {
 fmt.Println(translateFunc(translationID, 1, map[string]interface{}{
  "Person": "Bob",
 }))
 fmt.Println(translateFunc(translationID, args))
 return translateFunc(translationID, args)
}` I've got the output _Bob has 1 unread email.
person_unread_email_count_